# SPARQL is it possible to bind two variables with their labels with a static text?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

This is my query

```
PREFIX : <http://example.org/rs#>

select ?item (SUM(?similarity) as ?summedSimilarity) 
(group_concat(distinct ?becauseOf ; separator = " , ") as ?reason) where
{
  values ?x {:instance1}
  {
    ?x  ?p  ?instance.
    ?item   ?p  ?instance.
    ?p  :hasSimilarityValue ?similarity
      bind (?p as ?becauseOf)
  }
  union
  {
    ?x  a   ?class.
    ?item   a   ?class.
    ?class  :hasSimilarityValue ?similarity
      bind (?class as ?becauseOf)
  }
  filter (?x != ?item)
}
group by ?item
```

in my first`bind` clause, I would like to not just bind the variable `?p`, but also the variable `?instance`. Plus, adding a text like `that is why`.

so the first bind should result the following results:
`?p that is why ?instance`

is that possible in SPARQL ?

**please don't care about if the data makes sence or not, it is just a query to show you my question**

Comment: May I ask why you bind a variable in a part of the union as a variable of the outer query? Is not easier to just use the variable name `becauseOf` then?

Comment: @AKSW obviously because of the question that I'm asking now, I don't want the variable ?becauseOf to be bind just to the varaible ?p, or the variable ?class, I want to do what I'm asking for in this question, which is, binding two variables and a static text to the ?becauseOf variable

Comment: **"in my firstbind clause, I would like to not just bind the variable ?p, but also the variable ?instance. Plus, adding a text like that is why."** You're not binding the variable ?p, you're binding the variable ?becauseOf to the value of ?p.  As per your instruction, I'm not worried about whether the data makes sense, but I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, either  Do you just want something like `bind(concat(str(?p)," that is why ", str(?instance)) as ?becauseOf)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're just looking for the [**concat**](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-concat) function. As I've mentioned before, you should really browse through the [SPARQL 1.1 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/), at least through the table of contents.  You don't need to memorize it, but it will give you an idea of what things are possible, and an idea of where to look.  Additionally, it's **very helpful** if you provide sample data that we can work with, because it makes it **much clearer** to figure out what you're trying to do.  The phrasing of your title was not particularly clear, and the question doesn't really provide an example of what you're trying to accomplish.  Only because I've seen some of your past questions did I have an idea of what you were aiming for.  At any rate, here's some data:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:p :hasSimilarity 0.3 .
:A :hasSimilarity 0.6 .

:a :p :b ;  #-- is is related to :b
   a  :A .  #-- and is an :A .

:c :p :b .  #-- :c is also related to :b

:d a :A .   #-- :d is also an :A .

:e :p :b ;  #-- :e is related to :b 
   a  :A .  #-- and is also an :A .
```

And here's the query and its results.  You just use **concat** to join the **str** form of your variables with the appropriate strings and then **bind** the result to the variable.

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?item
       (sum(?factor_) as ?factor)
       (group_concat(distinct ?reason_; separator=", ") as ?reason)
{
  values ?x { :a }

  { ?x    ?p ?instance .
    ?item ?p ?instance .
    ?p :hasSimilarity ?factor_ .
    bind(concat("has common ",str(?p)," value ",str(?instance)) as ?reason_) }
  union
  { ?x     a ?class.
    ?item  a ?class.
    ?class :hasSimilarity ?factor_ .
    bind(concat("has common class ",str(?class)) as ?reason_)
  }
  filter (?x != ?item)
}
group by ?item
```

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| item | factor | reason                                                          |
===================================================================================
| :c   | 0.3    | "has common urn:ex:p value urn:ex:b"                            |
| :d   | 0.6    | "has common class urn:ex:A"                                     |
| :e   | 0.9    | "has common urn:ex:p value urn:ex:b, has common class urn:ex:A" |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```